Is any browser supported for OSX 10.6.8?
I have a MacBook 10 circa 2007.  I found a way to install Linux, but it sucks (slow, 5 minute boot).  Lubuntu, Mint force upgrades on me that kill performance. I can go back to beautiful Snow Leopard, but I can't use Internet., every browser Safari, Firefox,, Chrome report I need to upgrade OSx, but no upgrade possible.  Is there a browser i am missing that runs on 10.6.8?  Besides a museum donation, how do I use a very old white first edition MacBook?

Welcome to Ask Different. Lynx browser is still maintained and a viable option for text, but can you edit this to explain what sites you need to access nd what browser features you prefer to work?

Are you sure you Mac does not support 10.7? There does seem to be more browsers available.

@bmike: I did get Lynx to install on Snow Leopard by using Mac Ports. The browser is text based, which I found to be amusing, but otherwise useless.

try the last contributor on this page, first link. It's an old version of Firefox. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1164864

The developer of Firefox Dynasty (modern Firefox backported to old OS X) is hoping to eventually get the browser working on 10.6. It's not there yet, however--currently, Firefox Dynasty works fully on 10.8 and partially works (with graphical glitches) on 10.7. It might be worth checking in again a few months from now.

A quick Google for "browsers for Snow Leopard" brings up lots of pages, including InterWebSnow.
https://github.com/wicknix/InterWebSnow/releases/tag/60.9.9
Though development does seem to have stopped.
There's also a lengthy blog on the subject:
https://blog.greggant.com/posts/2024/07/03/running-10.6-snow-leopard-in-2024.html
.. which includes a number of browser alternatives; but ultimately concludes that you shouldn't use Snow Leopard for daily work.
A 2007 MacBook should run Lion, at least, which will give you more options.
As for Linux: most reports suggest that Linux is often faster on old Macs than macOS. I presume you've switched the old hard drive for an SSD?
But as you imply: this is a 17-year-old Mac, and unless there's a particular function that you need, you really need to get a new computer.
